# Flex DataGrid with larrge number of columns

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, adobe

I have a Flex DataGrid with large number of columns, and the rendering tooks too much time ando sometimes it ends with timeout(function timeout).

Is there any strategies to improve the performance when rendering a large amount of columns.

Comment: Define `large`. I have one with 32 columns that renders just fine and that's just about as many columns as one can fit into a screen. If it's much more than that, you might want to review your UI.

Comment: Try setting horizontalSCrollPolicy to auto

Comment: Did this work for you?